# How do i retrieve input values in a script?

Tags: javascript, html, input, var

I don't know why it doesn't work. How can i retrieve the input value?

```
<body>
   <script>
      function toCelsius() {
         var g = document.getElementById("f").innerHTML;
         var b = (5/9) * (g-32);
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = b;
   </script>
   Fahrenheit = <input id="f" type=text size=6>
   <input type=button value="Bereken" onClick="toCelsius()"> 
   <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

> ```
> document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = b;
> ```

Runs when:

- when `demo` doesn't exist in the document
- when `b` hasn't been defined
- where `b` is out of scope (because `b` is defined inside the function)

You need to move that line **inside** the function

This line:

> ```
> var g = document.getElementById("f").innerHTML;
> ```

… tries to read the children of an input element, but inputs are void elements: They don't have children.

You need to read the **value** of the input instead.

```html
<body>
  <script>
    function toCelsius() {
      var g = document.getElementById("f").value;
      var b = (5 / 9) * (g - 32);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = b;
    }
  </script>

  Fahrenheit =
  <input id="f" type=text size=6>
  <input type=button value="Bereken" onClick="toCelsius()">

  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the "script" tag should be left before closing the body.

To retrieve the value of input, use `document.getElementById("f").value;`

See my example: http://codepen.io/joaocarvalhowd-1472219370/pen/apMywY

Answer (score -2):

The innerHTML property is part of the Document Object Model (DOM) that allows Javascript code to manipulate a website being displayed. Specifically, it allows reading and replacing everything within a given DOM element (HTML tag)

To get the value from a input field you need to use

```
var your_var = document.getElementById("filed-id").value;
```

So, your final code will be as follows:

```
<body>
    <script>
    function toCelsius() {
        var g = document.getElementById("f").value;
        var b = (5/9) * (g-32);
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = b;
    </script>

                    Fahrenheit = <input id="f" type=text size=6>
                    <input type=button value="Bereken"         onClick="toCelsius()"> 

                    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
```